# Python: How to match a string with generic date in middle

Tags: python, regex

Looking for the pythonic way of matching a string (filename in my case) with any date in the format in middle of the string.

Eg. python-1u222-ea-str-b08-**10_dec_2018**.zip
I am trying to get the python way to match the above string with any date in lieu of 10_dec_2018

```
element = "python-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip"
m = re.match("python-1u222-ea-str-b08-\"+\"[\d]{1,2}_[ADFJMNOS]\w*_[\d]{4}\"+\".zip",element)
if m:
    print("Hurray!!! ")
else:
    print(element, " : doesn't match")
```

This is what I tried, but doesn't match. I feel multiple double quotes in re.match is the culprit here. I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you included these escaped ("backslashed") double quotes and the plus signs after them in your regex. None of these are needed

Comment: Oh!! That was a for a test @ForceBru. And I forgot to remove while posting the question. Editing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

element = "python-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip"
m = re.match("python-1u222-ea-str-b08-[\d]{1,2}_\w{3}_[\d]{4}.zip", element)

print("Hurray!!! ") if m else print(f"'{element}' doesn't match")
```

Output:

`Hurray!!!`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
wanted_text = "python-1u222-ea-str-b08"
test = "python-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip"

if wanted_text in test:
  print("Hurray")
else:
  print("doesn't match")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we have some missing leads here. I am rephrasing it in a required way.

I am having a list of several files like:

```
python-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip
pyth_plugin-1u222-ea-str-b08-windows-10_dec_2018.zip 
pyth_plugin-1u222-ea-str-windows.zip 
python-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip 
python-1u222-ea-str-b08-sec-10_dec_2018.zip 
python-1u222-ea-str-b08-sec_bcc-10_dec_2018.zip 
pyt-1u222-ea-str-security.zip 
pyt-1u222-ea-str-security_ecc.zip 
pyt-1u222-ea-str.zip 
epython-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip 
epyt-1u222-ea-str.zip
```

The date in these filenames will change. I am looking for a way to check for the existence of each of these files, but with only different dates.

In my question, python-1u222-ea-str-b08-10_dec_2018.zip is just an example.